# "VALID" padding wrong algorithm

Tags: tensorflow

I've been using TensorFlow to test some AlexNet CNNs, and came across some irregularity in the algorithm for 2D convolution, more precisely in the *padding* options.

[TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution) uses:

`out_height = ceil(float(in_height - filter_height + 1) / float(strides[1]))`

while [most approaches](https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-Part-2/) use:

`out_height = ceil(float(in_height - filter_height) / float(strides[1]) + 1)`

In my case this leads to an output size of 26x26 in the first convolutional layer, where it should be 27x27, as mentioned in all AlexNet implementations... Do you know why TensorFlow has an apparently wrong calculation?